# List of same images -> Find intervals of same images

Tags: list-manipulation, image-processing, visualization

I have a list of images.
There are some **similar** ones.
Now, I would like to create a list, wich tells me the interval of those similar images.  How can I do it ?

For instance:

[image]

and the result should be:

```
intervalSimIm = {{1,6},{7},{8,11},{12}}
```

Here are the images, if you want to try it out:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/arp1v6i3a7hp802/AADy3XfJ2WxSOqnMBnTBJbaWa?dl=0

Comment: Can you zip up the images you have and put it on e.g. Dropbox? Other people can't experiment if they don't have your images.

Comment: @J.M. sure, I added a link in the description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Split[Range @ Length @ similarImages, 
  ImageDistance[similarImages[[#]], similarImages[[#2]]] <= 100 &][[All, {1, -1}]] /. 
 {x_, x_} :> {x}
```

> {{1, 6}, {7}, {8, 11}, {12}}

Comment: Awesome !! Thank you very much!

Comment: @totyped, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 0):

`ImageDistance` hard to work on more complicated case. There are two methods maybe can give more stable result, and it can make you leave those magic threshold.

```
imgs = Import["E:\\download\\Similar_images.zip", "*.png"];
```

[image]

### Mehtod one

```
FindClusters[MapIndexed[# -> First[#2] &, imgs]]
```

> `{{1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12},{2},{10}}`

### Method two

This will cost your more time, but I think it is stronger.

```
fe = FeatureExtraction[imgs];
fd = FeatureDistance[fe];
FindClusters[MapIndexed[# -> First[#2] &, imgs], DistanceFunction -> fd]
```

> `{{1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12},{2},{10}}`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I cannot find FeatureExtraction on my Mathematica (10.4).